# Formatting preview of DateTime-column in XamDataGrid when editor is XamComboEditor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, infragistics

I have an Infragistics `XamDataGrid` with a field that is bound to a DateTime. Since the user only can choose from a predefined set of dates, I use a `XamComboEditor` to edit the field. I want to specify formatting for the dates and I have successfully been able to do so for the drop down. However, I'm not able to set the date format of the "preview" of the field (i.e. when the field is not in edit mode).

In the drop down, the format is correct, e.g. "01/06/2010 12:00:00", but in the preview column this is rendered as "06/01/2010 12:00:00". How do I set the date format of the "preview"?

The XAML for the field:

```
<igWPF:Field Name="ReferenceDate" Label="Reference date">
    <igWPF:Field.Settings>
        <igWPF:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igWPF:XamComboEditor}">
            <igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:XamComboEditor}">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBoxStyle">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <!-- Works just fine, but only in edit-mode -->
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource dateTimeConverter}}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding DataItem.ReferenceDate}" />
                            </Style>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataItem.AvailableReferenceDates}"/>
                    <Setter Property="DropDownResizeMode" Value="None"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding DataItem.HasVariance, Converter={StaticResource invertBooleanConverter}}" />
                    <!-- Does not seem to work -->
                    <Setter Property="Format" Value="{x:Static ValueConverters:DateTimeLongFormatConverter.DateFormat}" />
                </Style>
            </igWPF:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
        </igWPF:FieldSettings>
    </igWPF:Field.Settings>
</igWPF:Field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking into this, but I wasn’t able to reproduce your behavior. I used the following Format “dd-MMM” and it works as expected. Could you please try to set the format like this and see if it works for you?

Also I found this post duplicate to the one in Infragistics' forum:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/83648/417940.aspx

which is already discussed. In the future I can suugest you post your questions related to Infragistics controls there, because this way you will get an answer from an Infragistics expert.